# Bash Option menu in git hook

Tags: git, bash

I'd like to presesnt a bash menu when a developer switches branches. 
I've created a post-checkout hook  like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

options=("Quit" "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" )
optionsprompt='Please enter your choice: '

sub1=("Option 1 sub 1" "Option 1 sub 2")
sub1prompt='Please enter your choice: '

PS3=$optionsprompt
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
         "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            PS3=$sub1prompt
            select sub1opt in "${sub1[@]}"
            do
                case $sub1opt in
                    "Option 1 sub 1")
                        echo "you chose choice 2"
                        ;;
                    "Option 1 sub 2")
                        echo "you chose choice 2"
                        ;;
                 esac
            done
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;

        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

When i execute this hook manually

```
./post-checkout
```

it presents me a menu as expected.
But when this hook is executed after switching branches, it doesn't wait for somebody to input a value, but after presenting the menu, the script ends.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, `post-checkout` has its standard input connected to `/dev/null`, so the `select` immediately fails to read any input. (I can't find this documented anywhere, but was able to confirm it using `strace`.) One solution is to simply redirect standard input from the terminal:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    ...
done < /dev/tty
```